# Upload image to firebase storage via HTTP Post

Tags: http, flutter, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, flutter-web

I want to upload an image into firebase storage in flutter web application.
What i've done so far:

- Receive a signedURL via cloud functions; as described here [Google guideline: Create signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#multipart_data_and_file_uploads) - at the bottom of the article
- Load the image from local file via flutter package "image_picker_web" [Package-Link](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_web)
- the picker provides (Image-)Widget, Uint8List, html.File
- try to upload image via MultipartRequest to the signedURL, BUT receive an Error: `XMLHttpRequest error`, but without any further details.

My code for the MultipartRequest (bytes of type Uint8List):

```
var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
  'image', bytes, filename: 'test.jpeg', // optional
  contentType: new MediaType('image', 'jpeg'),
);
var uri = Uri.parse(url);
var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri)
  ..files.add(multipartFile);
var response = await request.send();
if (response.statusCode == 200) print('Uploaded!');
response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
    print(value);
  });
```

...i also tried with stream:

```
var stream = http.ByteStream.fromBytes(bytes);
var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('file', stream, bytes.length,
      filename: 'test.jpeg', contentType: new MediaType('image', 'jpeg'));
```

I assume there is something wrong with the image data/type (MultipartFile) or the url doesn't work or the complete MultipartRequest doesn't conform to firebase storage

Does anybody has a solution for this or how can i investigate the problem further?

Answer (score 0):

If you check your browser console, you will most probably be getting a CORS error.

There is a better way to upload an image to Firebase, here is the code to upload the image, and receive the URL where it is stored.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;
import 'dart:html' as html;

String url;

Future<String> uploadProfilePhoto(html.File image, {String imageName}) async {
  try {
    //Upload Profile Photo
    fb.StorageReference _storage = fb.storage().ref('displayPhotos/$imageName');
    fb.UploadTaskSnapshot uploadTaskSnapshot = await _storage.put(image).future;
    // Wait until the file is uploaded then store the download url
    var imageUri = await uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    url = imageUri.toString();
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  return url;
}
```

Comment: This is not what the OP requested. He wanted a way to upload images by HTTP post, not using the Firebase Storage plugin.

Comment: @MAA - This question is a year old. Whether he wanted to it via HTTP Post or not, I have provided a working solution. This removes any CORS issues when working with POST requests.